# Generating HTML TestResults with XUnit

Tags: c#, .net, testing, xunit

How can I generate nice HTML Test Results with xUnit ?

I have tried to run my tests with **dotnet test --logger html** however this test result does not show the class names and method names the ones passed. It shows if there is a failure as output like this: [image: testResult.html]

I am actually okay if there is a way to show passed test class names and method names here too.
Another way that I have tried this command **dotnet test --logger:xunit** and that creates a .trx

as output like this:[image: .trx report]

Another way that I was able to create was .xml as like this: [image: .xml test report]

All I want to do is to either convert one of them to test report like this: [image: HTML Test Report]

or find a way to add a class name and method name that passed in the very first test report that generated by **dotnet test --logger html**

Comment: If you are using xunit, why are you tagging other test frameworks like nunit and testng? Please remove those tags if they are not relevant to your question.

Comment: the reason I added nUnit was xUnit is advanced version of it according to its developers. Reason I added testNG was to i think testNG is used widely in testing community . I appreciate help..

Comment: You can use Cobertura to have different formats for your results.

Comment: Many of us use filters, so we only see questions in our areas of expertise. The NUnit tag here feels deceptive, because it makes a non-nunit question appear in my nunit feed and makes me spend a little time on it - without helping you in any way.

Comment: I have [almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75461932/) and my current fill-in is to [use the xml output and xsl to generate an html page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465232/819887). It might be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

With many tools, there are two different steps:

1. Calculate code coverage
2. Format code coverage results as HTML

The first step usually creates a machine-readable XML or JSON file, as you have already discovered.

This machine-readable file needs to be nicely formatted in the second step as HTML. We're using [ReportGenerator](https://reportgenerator.io/getstarted) for this, it's pretty straightforward.

But there are also other tools that wrap those two steps into a single call, e. g. *JetBrains dotCover*. They have a console runner for free and you can find out more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html#cover).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little late to the party but the first screenshot you show is the collapsed view of the xunit test results.

If you click the line ending with the dll name, it expands to show you all the tests that passed.

This is working for me on a .NET 6 xunit project. I can see the classes, methods, parameters and execution duration.